# I'm trying to web scrape ebay using python and BeautifulSoup, but I'm getting a list index out of rangeerror

Tags: python, html, ebay-api

As in the title, I'm trying to write a Ebay web-scrape program, yet when I try to find the price, it creates a list error, yet it works for getting the product name.

The url is: https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=switch&_sacat=0&_pgn=1

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

**Open Collection**

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close
```

**grabs each products**

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",  {"class" : "s-item__wrapper clearfix"})

filename = "EbayWebscraping.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "product_name, quality"

for container in containers:

    title_container = container.findAll('h3', {'class' : 's-item__title'} )
    product_name = title_container[0].text
```

#Where the problem is#

```
    price_container = container.findAll('span', {'class' : 's-item__price'})
    price = price_container[0].text



    print('Product: ' + product_name)
    print('Price: ' + price)
```

Comment: Hey @Cole Malcolm can you share the url if possible!

Comment: @Bhavya Parikh done

Answer (score 0):

if you see `containers` in which at index 0 there is no product or price info so you can start from index 1 and also you can use `try-except` instead of that

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=switch&_sacat=0&_pgn=1")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")

containers = soup.findAll("div",  {"class" : "s-item__wrapper clearfix"})[1:]
for container in containers: 
        print(container.find('h3', {'class' : 's-item__title'} ).text)
        print(container.find("span", class_="s-item__price").text)
```

Output:

```
30 in 1 Game Collection Nintendo Switch Brand New Sealed
AU $47.00
Street Fighter 30th Anniversary Collection Nintendo Switch Brand New Sealed
AU $47.00
For Nintendo Switch Case ZUSLAB Clear Slim Soft Heavy Duty Shockproof Cover
AU $9.99 to AU $16.95
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if the selector is present before doing further processing:

```py
if container.findAll('span', {'class' : 's-item__price'}):
    # do something
```

You also don't need to access `[0]` index. `text` would work perfectly. Additionally, there's no need to use `findAll` since you already extracting data from `containers` and its selector that contains data about title, price inside. Think of the container as [matryoshka doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) if it makes more sense.

You just have to call text and price selectors e.g:

```py
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",  {"class" : "s-item__wrapper clearfix"})

for container in containers:
    product_name  = container.find('h3', {'class' : 's-item__title'}).text
    price = container.find('span', {'class' : 's-item__price'}).text
```

Code that paginates through all pages and [example in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-ebay-using-python-and-beautifulsoup#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
}
    
params = {
    '_nkw': 'switch',              # search query  
    '_pgn': 1                      # page number
}

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html', params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    print(f"Extracting page: {params['_pgn']}")

    print("-" * 10)
    
    for products in soup.select(".s-item__info"):
        title = products.select_one(".s-item__title span").text
        price = products.select_one(".s-item__price").text
        link = products.select_one(".s-item__link")["href"]
        
        data.append({
          "title" : title,
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })

    if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output

```json
Extracting page: 1
----------
[
  {
    "title": "Shop on eBay",
    "price": "$20.00",
    "link": "https://ebay.com/itm/123456?hash=item28caef0a3a:g:E3kAAOSwlGJiMikD&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAsJoWXGf0hxNZspTmhb8%2FTJCCurAWCHuXJ2Xi3S9cwXL6BX04zSEiVaDMCvsUbApftgXEAHGJU1ZGugZO%2FnW1U7Gb6vgoL%2BmXlqCbLkwoZfF3AUAK8YvJ5B4%2BnhFA7ID4dxpYs4jjExEnN5SR2g1mQe7QtLkmGt%2FZ%2FbH2W62cXPuKbf550ExbnBPO2QJyZTXYCuw5KVkMdFMDuoB4p3FwJKcSPzez5kyQyVjyiIq6PB2q%7Ctkp%3ABlBMULq7kqyXYA"
  },
  {
    "title": "Jabra Elite 7 Pro - Black Certified Refurbished",
    "price": "$82.99",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/165621993671?epid=12050643207&hash=item268fd710c7:g:gMwAAOSwx8Bi9Fwg&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4NGq89JefbLJPItXeQ93BWhuE9Wt3pRHvU92HE2wiaGKAUlhQ8hDKu9iP2m5gdNQc8t8ujFSUwXJSyCxrnjh9qaxVXN0s0V7clbWiZTPr7Co3AwECpNLit29NfC%2BXbQxEv7kePJokjM9wnHv%2BAamoTlPl0K8BHa0S3FVrb7IUn9s%2FmvdzTiGUd4DHYNdIEQeFNK7zqB8%2BlWrukvfUz62JemzooE1UYtLbCtQwfIDP1F2GbOL4DoRwHXynUtpduYPA8TX6qZOv8eL44j4hNnP6%2BjGBaDGCReJ6ld13xxhYEUf%7Ctkp%3ABFBM3qnT0f5g"
  },
  {
    "title": "New Listingnintendo switch bundle ",
    "price": "$225.00",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/354344900745?hash=item52809a1889:g:egsAAOSw-qZjUQl-&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4MkbjLSYGoCVhjI%2BBE%2F1cIoqAfUyH73WJdSL7XugI%2BMtaCzRdexKqk3SnxM3PT5yMHSrChuJdcLC6ESDVvNs2j01yTzx8Cl9i9CQbV89Gp9tzPQNIaBGkVwSh989DJ4lmSmCKywnPQ9yLQqY3fz96kBJbbZwGd63yks4tTuZOiNcAl7PTriDOrVNHF%2FUXm3s18tajQeqtrZxW4pb8nWa5%2FtdmrwDphxTKmA9sONVXfKX5oFujpDxrwswe%2FgoJi2XGjGqe06ruHbzH295EHuRLUv4Tn0R2Kf7CKaman2IEpPo%7Ctkp%3ABFBM3qnT0f5g"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [Ebay Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/ebay-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend.

Example code that paginates through all pages:

```py
from serpapi import EbaySearch
import os, json

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # serpapi api key    
    "engine": "ebay",                 # search engine
    "ebay_domain": "ebay.com",        # ebay domain
    "_nkw": "switch",                 # search query
    "_pgn": 1                         # page number                  
    "LH_Sold": "1"                    # shows sold items
}

search = EbaySearch(params)        # where data extraction happens

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dict

    if "error" in results:
        print(results["error"])
        break
    
    for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
        link = organic_result.get("link")
        price = organic_result.get("price")

        data.append({
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })
                    
    page_num += 1
    print(page_num)
    
    if "next" in results.get("pagination", {}):
        params['_pgn'] += 1

    else:
        break

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$70.00",
      "extracted": 70.0
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/334599074264?hash=item4de7a8b1d8:g:Vy4AAOSwLLNjUK2i&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAkKM1u%2BmETRpbgLxiKL9uymVFiae4NU2iJa00z6qQK4lyzoe477sEDhhVVjF39BDTAOJQ4PLP%2BoXj1xf5wH8Ja5v1oAmO%2FNRlSFlTK80FlnQkHpIYswiG%2BNH44f98M5LWkwgeOb%2FRVc9uU6Ep9HYaV9JV39LZFRiOJLOGgFvoRxLD4731y0VuzM%2BcPXThX7aXtA%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR4KOv9H-YA"
  },
  {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$169.95",
      "extracted": 169.95
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/185625421454?epid=4050657390&hash=item2b3823268e:g:WrIAAOSwPKdjPfvK&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoBkI9bwtrhJH9mDVPkHzYgem23XBXWHO%2FghvdNjkqq2RX%2BCoy33RIc%2FxXg%2BHWp0Y5jUL9%2BOfnpKyRshkZTRttODPLt%2Fu0VIfjunwr%2F6r9lKHiZ9w%2FnaITM0BTU0FeU1gKw2dERJwDKrzgCPNc%2FStsq0BdCUYNxQeLG4I1ezDBYZSseUv96U33wRLz%2BJ94pP6UgnCp2nj4oX3qFujBLsvG%2F8%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR4KOv9H-YA"
  },
  # ...
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.